# Strange behaviour of the tokenize module

Tags: python

I see some strange behaviour when using the `tokenize` module

```
import tokenize, io, sys
from contextlib import closing
source=u"""
for i in range(10):
    print "HELLO"
    if i==5:
        print "bingo"
"""
def parse():
    with closing(io.StringIO(source)) as f:
        for type, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline):
            print("%d,%d-%d,%d:\t%s\t%s" % (srow, scol, erow, ecol, tokenize.tok_name[type], repr(token)))
            yield type, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line

for token in tokenize.untokenize(parse()):
    sys.stdout.write(token)
```

The INDENT before the `if` is missing in the output to console. It happens for both python2 and 3.
Is this a known bug or am I using the module in a wrong way?

```
3,1-3,6:    NAME    u'print'
3,7-3,14:   STRING  u'"HELLO"'
3,14-3,15:  NEWLINE u'\n'
4,1-4,3:    NAME    u'if'
4,4-4,5:    NAME    u'i'
4,5-4,7:    OP  u'=='
```

I use tabs for indentation. When I replace the tabs by 4 spaces, I obtain the correct result

```
3,4-3,9:    NAME    u'print'
3,10-3,17:  STRING  u'"HELLO"'
3,17-3,18:  NEWLINE u'\n'
4,4-4,6:    NAME    u'if'
4,7-4,8:    NAME    u'i'
4,8-4,10:   OP  u'=='
4,10-4,11:  NUMBER  u'5'
4,11-4,12:  OP  u':'
```

The difference is the start column of `if` which is 1 when using tabs and 4 when using spaces.
It seems to be a bug in the 'untokenize' function that seems to output spaces instead of tabs.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: Why should it output tabs?

Comment: because the input code contains tabs. By inconsistently outputting tabs and spaces , untokenize produces an invalid python program. I would have no problem if the output was valid but it isn't. I therefore can't accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is exactly as it should be. Column index is 0 based. One `tab` is one character so `if` is correctly detected in column 1. When you change this `tab` to 4 `spaces` there are indeed 4 characters, so `if` is detected in column 4.
Proof from the output of your code:

```
1,0-1,1:    NL  u'\n'
2,0-2,3:    NAME    u'for'
```

As you can see, both `linefeed` in the first line and `for` in the second line are in column 0.
You might get confused because line numbers are 1 based.

*Footnote: You should use spaces for indentation. This is a convention which ensures consistent display of indents on another developer's machine. Displayed tab width may be adjusted and space width is just one character.*

**EDIT:**
After OP's comments arguing that there is a problem with `tokenize` and `untokenize` I must add the following note.
As [official documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.untokenize):
*The result is guaranteed to tokenize back to match the input so that the conversion is lossless and round-trips are assured. **The guarantee applies only to the token type and token string as the spacing between tokens (column positions) may change.***

Comment: And, the correct direct interpretion of tab is 8 spaces, not for.

Comment: @Elazar yes. I've never said that `tab` is interpreted as 4 `spaces`. OP has written that he replaced `tab` with 4 `spaces`, so I'm just accommodating to OP's statements. The fact that I'm using 4 spaces in my code is not relevant here.

Comment: I understand, I've only added to your answer :)

Comment: I am not confused with 0-based numbering. Using tabs in a python program is perfectly valid. When fed with a tab-based python program, i expect the tokenize-untokenize chain would output exactly the same input program. This seems to be valid only for space-based programs.

Comment: @user3172811 I'm not saying that using `tab` character is invalid. I'm saying it's discouraged - even by `PEP8` http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation and http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces Not following the convention leads you into trouble.

Comment: This doesn't invalidate the conclusion that there is a problem with "untokenize".

Comment: @user3172811: There's no problem with untokenize. It's working as intended.